# batch file to replace a line using sed inside a for loop doesn't work

Tags: loops, math, batch-file, for-loop, sed

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%g in (1,1,100) do (
  set /a c=%%g+1
  echo !c!
  echo c:\cygwin\bin\sed.exe -e 's/Token="%%g"/Token="!c!"/g' xyz.xml > xxx_!c!.xml
)
pause
```

I want to replace Token="n" with Token="n+1" in an xml file. The above script doesn't work.
Any help ?

Comment: Can you describe what the end result of your .bat does? I am guessing it has something to do with the `"!c!"` not getting expanded correctly, but hard to say just yet.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(
 for /L %%g in (100,-1,1) do (
   set /a c=%%g+1
   echo !c! >con:
   echo s/Token="%%g"/Token="!c!"/g
 )
)>xxx.sed
c:\cygwin\bin\sed.exe -f xxx.sed xyz.xml > xxx.xml
```

should see you right.  I'm not familiar with `cygwin/sed` syntax; the created file `xxx.sed` should contain appropriate SED instructions to make the changes (for n=1 to 100, replace [Token="n"] with [Token="n+1"])